# What Bluetooth HCI radio to use for Bluetooth v4.2 testing

Tags: bluetooth

I would like to test Bluetooth v4.2 features using a Raspberry (e.g. LE Secure Connections, Data Packet Length Extension, Link Layer Privacy, etc). I know that BlueZ is capable of this and I have everything set up and ready. The only thing missing is a Bluetooth v4.2/v5.0 HCI radio that I can connect to my Raspberry Pi to do the testing. Does such a radio exist? and if so are there any recommendations?